# How to catch exceptions in workers in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm working with the multiprocessing module in Python (2.7.3) and want to debug some stuff going on in my workers. However, I seem to not be able to catch any exceptions in the worker threads.

A minimal example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


a=[1]
def worker():
    print a[2]


def pool():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    pool.apply_async(worker, args = ())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "Multiprocessing done!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool()
```

This is expected to raise an IndexError, but my output only is

```
    Multiprocessing done!
```

Is there a way to show me all exceptions occuring in the worker threads without manually raising my own?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error is not raised unless you call [`get` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get) of [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) (the return value of the `apply_async`):

According to the [`AsyncResult.get` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get):

> Return the result when it arrives. If timeout is not None and the
>   result does not arrive within timeout seconds then
>   multiprocessing.TimeoutError is raised. **If the remote call raised an
>   exception then that exception will be reraised by get()**.

```
def pool():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    result = pool.apply_async(worker, args=())
    result.get() # <------------
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "Multiprocessing done!"
```

Comment: Wow, THAT was fast. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that was me by accident. I come back to this answer so often...However my downvote can't be canceled for 2 hours. Sorry.

Comment: If I don't want to wait for the process to finish and still wants to get exceptions, what can I do?
I mean using `result.get()` would block the code until the process is finished how to escape that?

Comment: AFAIK, exception -> cause the process termination. You need to wait the process end.

Answer (score 3):

I think falsetru gave you what you need. I'd just like to expand a little more.

If it's important for you to get not only the error but the original context (i.e. to know that the exception occurred on line 1 of worker()) then you can check [this nice post by Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html) which explains how to reraise exceptions with their original context.

That doesn't work for mp.Pool so it's just in case you need something more. [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent) covers your question using more explicit multiprocessing techniques instead of mp.Pool.