# Python Multiprocessing Doesnt Terminate On Base Exception

Tags: python, exception, python-multiprocessing

When running using multiprocessing pool, I find that the worker process keeps running past a point where an exception is thrown.

Consider the following code:

```
import multiprocessing


def worker(x):
    print("input: " + x)
    y = x + "_output"
    raise Exception("foobar")
    print("output: " + y)
    return(y)


def main():

    data = [str(x) for x in range(4)]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    chunksize = 1
    results = pool.map(worker, data, chunksize)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("Printing results:")
    print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is:

```
$ python multiprocessing_fail.py
input: 0
input: 1
input: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
input: 3
  File "multiprocessing_fail.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "multiprocessing_fail.py", line 16, in main
    results = pool.map(worker, data, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: foobar
```

As you can see, the worker process never proceeds beyond `raise Exception("foobar")` to the second print statement. However, it resumes work at the beginning of function worker() again and again.

I looked for an explanation in the documentation, but couldn't find any. Here is a potentially related SO question:

[Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool)

But that is different (about keyboard interrupts not being picked by the master process).

Another SO question:

[How to catch exceptions in workers in Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094852/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-workers-in-multiprocessing)

This question is also different, since in it the master process doesnt catch any exception, whereas here the master did catch the exception (line 16). More importantly, in that question the worker did not run past an exception (there is only one executable line for the worker).

Am running python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch exceptions in workers in Multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094852/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-workers-in-multiprocessing)

Comment: @jordanm thanks for the fast response! I read that question, and found it different from mine. Edited to bring out differences.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be running passed the exception. The string "output:" is never printed. It seems that after the exception is thrown and it dies, it's just spawning a new worker.

Comment: If you want the entire script to die after an exception in a child process, you will need to detect it and exit from the main process.

Comment: @jordanm I made the worker process print its id (using multiprocessing.current_process()) and it prints the same worker process id. It is the same worker process that moves past the exception.

Answer (score 1):

> **Comment**: Pool should start one worker since the code has pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1).
>
> > **From the Documnentation:**
> >     *A process pool object which controls a pool of worker processes to which jobs can be submitted*

---

> **Comment**: That one worker is running the worker() function multiple times
>
> > **From the Documentation:**
> >     `map(func, iterable[, chunksize])`
> >     This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as **separate tasks**.

Your `worker()` is the **separate task**. Renaming your `worker()` to `task()` could help to clarify what is what.

> **Comment**: What I expect is that the worker process crashes at the Exception

It does, the **separate task**, your `worker()` dies and `Pool` starts the next task.

**What you want is `Pool.terminate()`**

> **From the Documentation:**
>
> > `terminate()`
> >     Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work.

---

> **Question**: ...  I find that the worker process keeps running past a point where an exception is thrown.

You give `iteration data` to `Pool`, therfore `Pool` does what it have to do:
**Starting len(data) worker**.

```
data = [str(x) for x in range(4)]
```

The **main Question** is: What do you want to expect with

```
raise Exception("foobar")
```

Comment: Pool should start one worker since the code has `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)` . That one worker is running the worker() function multiple times (and hitting the exception multiple times as well).

What I expect is that the worker process crashes at the Exception since it is an unhandled exception. Unfortunately, the documentation says nothing about this situation.

Comment: Comment: Pool should start one worker since the code has pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1).

        From the Documnentation:
        `A process pool object which controls a pool of worker processes to which jobs can be submitted.`    

From the next line in the documentation:

`processes is the number of worker processes to use.`

and the invocation:

`class multiprocessing.Pool([processes[, initializer[, initargs[, maxtasksperchild]]]])` .  

So should start exactly one worker

Comment: comment: It does, the separate task, your worker() dies and Pool starts the next task.  The function worker() is a function object and cannot die. A process can die. The fact that the worker process (as you pointed out, different from the worker() function) doesn't die is the main question here.