# Python program not throwing error when called with wrong parameters in apply_async

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, apply-async

Hello this is a sample example of something that I want to do. I want to use threads in my application. It's working fine the issues is python is not throwing error when I by mistake call function with wrong parameter making it sometimes harder to debug.

Sample program :  as you can see I am calling `console_log` function with wrong number of arguments. When I run the program there is no output and it exits

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def console_log(id, msg):
    print("{} : {}".format(id, msg))

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
max_threads = 1
pool = ThreadPool(processes=max_threads)

for d in data:
    pool.apply_async(console_log, (d))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Same program but without threads and pools

```
def console_log(id, msg):
    print("{} : {}".format(id, msg))

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for d in data:
    console_log(d)
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "async.py", line 12, in <module>
    console_log(d)
TypeError: console_log() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

Why don't I get same error output when I use threadpool ? Is there a way to get that error message. I am using python version 3.8.10

UPDATE
error_callback can be used to return the error. So the function call becomes something like this

```
def callback_error(result):
    print('error', result)

pool.apply_async(console_log, (d,), error_callback=callback_error)
```

I found it through question suggestions. Link : [Exception thrown in multiprocessing Pool not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728236/exception-thrown-in-multiprocessing-pool-not-detected)

Comment: See also: [How to catch exceptions in workers in Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094852/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-workers-in-multiprocessing)

Comment: I have updated my question with the answer. Thanks for the link. I found error_callback to be right approach for me

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do

```
for d in data:
    pool.apply_async(console_log, (d,))
```

I know in the past it's complained if I didn't add that comma