# How to stop a function outside of it in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know how to stop a running function outside of it. Here is how it should be:

```
def smth():
    time.sleep(5) # Just an example
smth.stop()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you need to use multiprocess and [kill the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053618/how-to-to-terminate-process-using-pythons-multiprocessing) when you want to stop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def foo():
  print('Starting...')
  time.sleep(5)
  print('Done')

p = Process(target=foo) #make process
p.start() #start function

time.sleep(2) #wait 2 secs
p.terminate() #kill it
print('Killed')
```

Output:

```
Starting...
Killed
```

Basically, what this code does is:

1. Create a process `p` which runs the function `foo` when started
2. Wait 2 seconds to simulate doing other stuff
3. End the process `p` with `p.terminate()`

Since `p` never passes `time.sleep(5)` in `foo`, it doesn't print 'Done'

[Run this code online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/BoldEnergeticCamel#main.py)