# Using multiprocessing for confirm that the client has received the message

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using the module socket for python, I did my server and my client but there is a problem: sometimes my client doesn't receive the message from the server, because I guess that the server sent the message before that the client is listening. I thought to do something like that:

```
HEADER = 64 
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

while(response =! "received"):
    client1.send("hello")
    response = client1.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
```

This can't work because the function recv() wait until the package come. I want to use the multiprocessing module, but I don't like how, can somebody help me?

Comment: why not just set a timeout on the socket?

Comment: How can I do it? Can you help me with an example or with some link? thanks

Comment: it's difficult to know what to suggest, your code doesn't give much to go on.  see https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout for the docs and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for what makes a good question

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with threading module? It is simple to work with. I have tested it for socket `recv()` method before and worked fine.

Comment: Is the first time that I use this module, but it works pretty good, the only problem is that sometimes server send message before that client starts listening, so client just remain on listening and can't go on. Is there a solution for the method `recv()` to stop listening after n seconds?

Comment: I used this method for real-time continuous connection and because of that, client was always listening. But if you put this method inside an individual process, you might be able to kill that process after n seconds, or alternatively execute the process every n seconds (periodically).

Comment: I'm going to try, but I didn't find some function that can kill a process, there is process.start() but I think there is no function.stop() or something like that.

Comment: Take a look at this link, it may help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053618/how-to-to-terminate-process-using-pythons-multiprocessing)