# Simple python multiprocessing pool doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def square(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

I'm trying to use multiprocessing using python 
for tutorial, I copied above code and run it, but it doesn't terminate 
What is the problem?

I use python 3.8.5 on Windows

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053618/how-to-to-terminate-process-using-pythons-multiprocessing

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't terminate? I just ran the same code and it runs to completion just fine

Comment: I mean, it keeps running like it fell into infinite loop

Comment: Which IDE? Try with running from terminal.