# Checking exit code of spawned processes in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a table in MySql which has 10 Million records. The table structure is :

```
EmpNo INT,
EmpName Varchar(20),
Salary INT
```

I want to extract all these records and trim spaces from column# 2 (i.e. Emp_name). However, time is of the essence and hence I want to break these records into chunks of 1 Mil records each and  processes them in parallel and finally combine them into 1 file. I believe I have to use Multiprocessing in this case. Can anyone please help me achieve this. I guess I'll have to use `p1.start(), p2.start(),...pn.start()` function and subsequently `p1.join(), p2.join()` etc, but is there a way to check if each of the spawned processes' `pid` have executed successfully ?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Multiprocessing: Handling Child Errors in Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent)