# Python Multiprocesing apply_async running erratically

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've recently been encountering a problem with Python's multiprocessing package that has me baffled. In a program, I have the following lines of code:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

...

def logResult(result):
    results.append(result)

cpu = mp.cpu_count()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=cpu)

results = []
num = 400 # A tunable parameter
for x in range(0, num):
    pool.apply_async(integrationFunction, args=(<some list of arguments...>), callback=logResult)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(len(results)) # Unpredictable

...
```

I cant really reveal exactly what happens in `integrationFunction`, but I know the following:
 - It uses `numpy.dblquad` at some point, and can be quite slow.

The problem is that in the last line of code, where I print the length of the `results` list, I get an erratic result every time I run the program - it usually prints some number around 100-120 when `num` is 400, but on odd occasions, it may print numbers outside of the range (and sometimes, even 0). But I expect it to print exactly `num` (which is 400 in this example) - what might be some reasons this is occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain `integrationFunction` is not throwing exceptions? That's the most likely reason to me of the "erratic behaviour".

Comment: I do not see any errors or warnings, and the integration function never is an exception explicitly thrown. Is it possible that some are getting suppressed in dblquad?

Comment: `dblquad` can e.g. throw `ValueError` and number of other exceptions caused by e.g. your OS or input. How do you check for exceptions in child processes? Some guidelines you can find e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent