# In python, how can I check if a child process exited cleanly or with an error?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have some code like this

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

processes = []
for i in range(10):
  p = mp.Process(target=my_func, args=args)
  processes.append(p)
  p.start()

for p in processes:
  p.join()
```

If there is a bug in `my_func` that causes all the threads to crash, then I want my parent process to detect that and also throw an exception. How can I detect if the process exited cleanly when I join the processes?

Comment: What exception you get?

Comment: Doesn't matter what exception I get. I keep making bugs in the my_func function and it causes the threads to exit and the program to continue. What I want is for if the threads exit with an exception that then the master process can detect it and exit as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Multiprocessing: Handling Child Errors in Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the value of the process' `exitcode`:

- `None` if the process has not finished yet.
- `0` if the process ended successfully.
- `N` if the process had an error, and exited with code N.
- `-N` if the process was killed with the signal `N`. (eg. -15 if killed by `SIGTERM`)

For example, in your main process:

```
for p in processes:
    p.join()
    if p.exitcode > 0:
        raise ValueError(f'a process exited with code {p.exitcode}')
```

And in your runnable:

```
try:
    do_something()
except KnownError as _:
    exit(my_known_error_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check exit code after calling `join()`.

For example:

```py
for p in processes:
  p.join()
  if p.exitcode is not 0:
    exit(1)
```

---

Reference:

- [multiprocessing.Process.exitcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.exitcode)