# Exception handling in Pool callback

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Given this example scenario:

```py
def _callback(result):
    if result == 2:
        # introduce an exception into one of the callbacks
        raise Exception("foo")

    print (result)

def _target(v):
    return v

worker_pool = Pool()

for i in range(10):
    worker_pool.apply_async(_target, args=(i,), callback=_callback)

worker_pool.close()
worker_pool.join()
```

I was hoping to see each value of `i` printed except for `i=2`, which would instead have yielded an exception.

Instead I see something like the following:

```
0
1
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 479, in _handle_results
    cache[job]._set(i, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 649, in _set
    self._callback(self._value)
  File "test3.py", line 6, in _callback
    raise Exception("foo")
Exception: foo
```

... and then execution just hangs.

I'm aware that `Pool` handles callbacks on a separate thread, but why would execution hang and how can I reliably guard against errors in a task's callback?

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if it helps. It explains error handling in subprocesses for python, which is what you might need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the exception inside the callback method is basically killing the thread that handles the `Pool`, as [it does not have an `except` block](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9cd01ece78e63bf98a1d25f70d5a020adf07ca4a/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L571) to handle this kind of situation. After the `Thread` is dead, [it's unable to `join` the `worker_pool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9cd01ece78e63bf98a1d25f70d5a020adf07ca4a/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L656), so your application hangs.

I believe that's a decision made by the Python maintainers, so the best way to handle this exception is to envelop your code inside a try/except block and handle it, instead of bubbling and letting the thread be killed.