# Running python script in windows..? ImportError: No module named 'twisted'

Tags: python, twisted.internet

I am new to python. Here is my question.
I have installed python 3.2 and my application is running fine. I am doing a client server socket tcp listen code in python. when I try to run the code in python shell it is throwing error saying that "**twisted**"  ImportError: No module named 'twisted'. Since I am using python 3.2. I read some where that twisted library comes up with the latest version.

I suppose what I am doing is wright. or If I have to install twisted from some where else or install the lower version of python...?

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3 seems to suggest that twisted will work with 3.3 onwards (or 2.6/2.7) - maybe check on alternatives for your version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824418/a-clean-lightweight-alternative-to-pythons-twisted