# Nonblocking django?

Tags: python, django, perl, nonblocking, mojolicious

At work I'm not allowed to use perl for web services. Python is allowed however.

What I need to do is serve up the results of some very slow c++ binaries. Each exe takes up to 20 seconds to run. In perl I'd just use mojolicious's non blocking event loop ( an example.of which is given here. http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2014/01/writing-non-blocking-applications-with-mojolicious-part-3.html )

How would one go about doing this with django and python?

Comment: Django is more about web-apps, not servers. You can use the built-in python module [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), which is very simple and low-level, or any of the reactor frameworks listed in the answers below (which are usually more powerful, but might be overkill, depending on what you're looking for)

Comment: What you really need is a port of [AnyEvent::Util](http://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent::Util)'s fork_call (as I have been building myself with [Mojo::IOLoop::ForkCall](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::IOLoop::ForkCall)) and integrate it into some python event loop. Then again, you could talk your `$work` into letting you use the right tool for the job :-)

Answer (score 6):

[Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) using non blocking IO , the concepts are the same as in perl or node js event loop, multiple tasks per thread and so on.

Answer (score 4):

*Probably* won't be possible with Django, as the entire framework will need to be built specifically for running inside an event loop. In an event-driven framework, slow operations (I/O for example) needs to be implemented using callbacks, so that the actual I/O can be offloaded to the event loop itself, and the callback only called when the operation has finished; Django is not implemented like this.

Take a look at [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/WebDevelopmentWithTwisted) — it is an event-driven networking engine for Python that also has some web application frameworks built on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [A clean, lightweight alternative to Python's twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824418/a-clean-lightweight-alternative-to-pythons-twisted). I'd choose [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) for a web app, as it runs with [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/)--the most versatile web server to run Python code.